# how to add all views in scroll view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i am facing a problem I created a layout for ringtone name and buttons and now I wanted to add more ringtone names and buttons but the problem is I want to make the layout scrollable and when I add scroll view at the starting of my layout code it says that scroll can only have one child.

The problem is the list I created contains relative as a linear layout to create a list of ringtone names.

Please help me to make this layout scrollable so that I can add more ringtones to it.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play4" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play6" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: insert another layout at the top and have a scroll view there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play2" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play3" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play4" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview3"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play5" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play6" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview5"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But for best practices use the Recyclerview instead of adding view in LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play2"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play3" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play3"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play4" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play4"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play5"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:onClick="setBtn_play6" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play6"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/textview5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

But I guess the best way to do this is to use Recycler View.
    There are so many links for this like 
    https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview
    https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example
    https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/
    and many more.
For your problem -You should have one parent layout after ScrollView . Add all other views as children of New Parent view 
    `

```
<ScrollView
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
<Your all children views>
</Linearlayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation -

`ScrollView` can hold only one direct child. This means that, if you have complex layout with more view controls, you must enclose them inside another standard layout like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

So to make all your Ringtone RelativeLayout scrollable add a parent LinearLayout to them and then add ScrollView.
Also if you want to keep your Ad at the bottom of the page, add RelativeLayout as root.

I am assuming you have static Ringtone data. If you have Dynamic data you should use RecyclerView instead of added static ScrollView and static RelativeLayouts as suggested by Ambika in below answer.

Check below code for your answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play1" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play2" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play2"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting2"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play3" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play3"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting3"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play4" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play4"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting4"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview3"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play5" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play5"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting5"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:onClick="setBtn_play6" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_play6"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_setting6"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_grid_item6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/textview5"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: by using your code all the buttons and text are disappeared from the screen

Answer (score 0):

wrap your linear layout within a scroll view. So something like

```
<Scrollview
...
...>

  <LinearLayout
  ...
  ...>
    <RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout> 

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Also take a look at this SO thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057224/5876626

I would however recommend moving to a RecyclerView. Anything that can be done with a ScrollView can be accomplished with a RecyclerView.

Have a read here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38084115/5876626

Answer (score 0):

Put all views in a Linear layout and put this in a scroll view,Then put this whole scroll view in a Linear layout